# Youtube-dl - downloading several youtube videos at once in one command

Tags: download, youtube-dl

I know how to download 1 youtube video command, 1 youtube playlist command but I don't know how to download several youtube videos at once in one command. How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add all the URLs after the call to youtube-dl, like this:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc" http://vimeo.com/56015672 "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEBDE1E42B3A9BC37" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEge830cgHs"
```

Most shells also allow multi-line commands, like this:

```
youtube-dl \
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc" \
  http://vimeo.com/56015672 \
  "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEBDE1E42B3A9BC37" \
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEge830cgHs"
```

Don't forget to quote URLs that contain an ampersand (`&`) or - on some shells - a question mark (`?`). How you quote depends on your shell - on most shells, including the URL in `'` or `"` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @phihag :) !

Comment: Thank, but this is slow. How can all those videos be downloaded concurrently?

Answer (score 4):

You can write all urls in a text file (separated with a new line). As an example, let's write a text file called "urls" with this content:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7DpRIk4lKY
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx_tr69QV8CDB-nn-pc5YZbDsdgjIQSII
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kh1sF-sbkbw
```

Then in the shell write:

```sh
youtube-dl -a urls
```

But, this is if you run this command in the same path as the urls file.
If you want to run it from another location just add the path behind the file name like:

```sh
youtube-dl -a path/to/file/urls
```

Also, in this example I didn't include any file extension, but it can also have one like ".txt"

Answer (score 2):

While the existing answers cover downloading several videos sequentially, using xargs you can instead download multiple in parallel, which can complete much more quickly, as described by [alexanderluna on github](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/8546#issuecomment-535694818).

To run 10 downloads in parallel, for example, use the command

```
xargs -n 1 -P 10 youtube-dl < urls.txt
```

where the urls.txt file has the list of video links to download, one per line.